# Problems with multiple plots in R

Tags: r, plot, graphics

does anyone has an idea how I can do multiple plots in R with plot functions which doesn't support the standard multiple plot tools like `mfrow`, `layout` or `split.screen`? Basically I'm trying to plot an effect plot, a ordinary plot and a ctree plot into one graphic, something with the following layout:

```
layout( matrix(c(1,2,3), ncol = 3) )
layout.show(3)

dev.off()
```

Any help would be nice. My attempts with the standard functions are below.

```
set.seed(pi)
DF  <- data.frame( x = c(rnorm(50, 3), rnorm(50, 10)),
                   y = c(rnorm(50, 3), rnorm(50, 10)) )

ct  <- party::ctree( y ~ x, data = DF )

mod <- lm( y ~ x, data = DF )
eff <- effects::effect( "x", mod )

## Attempt 1 (mfrow):
par( mfrow = c(1,3) )

plot( eff )
plot( DF$x, DF$y )
plot( ct )

par( mfrow = c(1,1) )

dev.off()

## Attempt 2 (layout):
layout( matrix(c(1,2,3), ncol = 3) )

plot( eff )
plot( DF$x, DF$y )
plot( ct )

dev.off()

## Attempt 3 (split.screen):
split.screen( rbind( c(  0, 1/3,  0,  1),
                     c(1/3, 2/3,  0,  1),
                     c(2/3,   1,  0,  1) ) )
screen(1)
plot( ct )

screen(2)
plot(DF$x, DF$y )

screen(3)
plot( eff )

close.screen(all.screens = TRUE)
dev.off()
```

Comment: The functions seem to be using grid based graphics. Look at the code of `party:::plotTree`. Therefore you will have to combine them using `viewports()`. I am not familiar with them but you can try reading on `pushViewport` , `popViewport` and similar.

Comment: Perfect! With grid and some effort I did it. I post the answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Posts a clear defined question, does research and shares a great answer. We need more people like you on this site, well done.

Answer (score 1):

The following code does the right thing for me:

```
DF  <- data.frame( x = rnorm(100),
                   y = rnorm(100) )

ct  <- party::ctree( y ~ x, data = DF )

mod <- lm( y ~ x, data = DF )
eff <- effects::effect( "x", mod )

p_eff   <- plot( eff, main = '' )

plot.new()
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::pushViewport( grid::viewport( layout = grid::grid.layout(1, 3) ) )

## Plot 1 (effect plot):
grid::pushViewport( grid::viewport( layout.pos.col = 1 ) )
print( p_eff, newpage = FALSE )
grid::popViewport()

## Plot 2 (base plot):
grid::pushViewport( grid::viewport( layout.pos.col = 2 ) )
par( fig = gridBase::gridFIG(), new = TRUE )
plot( DF$x, DF$y )
grid::popViewport()

## Plot 3 (ctree plot):
grid::pushViewport( grid::viewport( layout.pos.col = 3 ) )
par( fig = gridBase::gridFIG(), new = TRUE )
plot( ct, newpage = FALSE )
grid::popViewport()
```